# Counting Occurrences of Text in a Column in a data frames containing separators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delimiter

I have a column in a data frame that contains values of what languages people have worked with. Each row is a new individual and the languages are separated by a delimiter(;).

[Column to be evaluated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B79Wx.png)

Is there any way to count occurrences of each language in the entire column,
eg, python occurs n times, JavaScript occurs N times, etc?

I tried this but I'm confused about how I could count the occurrences of each language in the entire column
`df['LanguageHaveWorkedWith'].value_counts()`

[what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTwpF.png)

I also tried to use `get_dummies` to one-hot encode it but how would I count the occurrences of each element?
`df['LanguageHaveWorkedWith'].str.get_dummies(sep = ';')`

[Get dummies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYoir.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use split data by separator, then explode, and calculate unique items counts

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Languages': ['Python;JavaScript;Java', 'Python;C++;Python;JavaScript', 'JavaScript;C++']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# 'Languages' split column by ';', then explode the list
df['Languages'] = df['Languages'].str.split(';')
df = df.explode('Languages')

# count each language sum
language_counts = df['Languages'].value_counts().reset_index()
language_counts.columns = ['Language', 'Count']
```